# Getting the updated value from @ObservedObject in SwiftUI

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, combine

I am trying to change the view when the user login, which is when the **isAuthenticated** is updated in the **Authentication** class, but it never gets the new value, I am not sure if I am understanding everything correctly.

**Authentication**

```
class Authentication: ObservableObject{

    @Published var email: String = ""
    @Published var password: String = ""
    @Published var isAuthenticated : Bool = false

    func login(){
        AppDelegate._bc.authenticateEmailPassword(email,
                                                  password: password,
                                                  forceCreate: false,
                                                  completionBlock: onAuthenticate,
                                                  errorCompletionBlock: onAuthenticateFailed,
                                                  cbObject: nil)
    }

    func onAuthenticate(serviceName:String?, serviceOperation:String?, jsonData:String?, cbObject: NSObject?) {

        /............./

        UserDefaults.standard.set(true, forKey: "HasAuthenticated")
        self.isAuthenticated.toggle()
        print("Login DONE!")
    }
}
```

Everything is okay till now, the user gets authenticated, it prints "Login DONE!" and it updates the **isAuthenticated** value to true.

But in the **AuthView** it does not receive the new value

**AuthView**

```
struct AuthView: View {

    @ObservedObject var auth = Authentication()

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView{
            VStack{
                /............./

                LoginView()

                NavigationLink(destination: ProfileView(), isActive: $auth.isAuthenticated) {
                    Text("")
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And here where I call the **login** function

**LoginView**

```
struct LoginView: View{

    @ObservedObject var auth = Authentication()

    var body: some View {
        VStack(){
            Button(action: {
                self.auth.login()
            }) {
                LoginButtonContent(state: "Login")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you say

```
@ObservedObject var auth = Authentication()
```

... in two different Views, those are two different Authentication objects. What happens in one cannot affect what happens in the other.

If your goal is to share a single Authentication object between views, you need an `@EnvironmentObject`.

Comment: Ohhh, I have tried this before but only changed it to @EnvironmentObject in the AuthView not in both views, I got it now and it's working, thank you very much for your help.